# Run alias after creation

Tags: shell, osx, alias

`alias xxx=echo && xxx ok` doesn't work, because alias in not available after `&&`. But one line code suits best my task.

How do I define alias and use in the same line in bash?

Comment: I don't understand the "why" part of your question. You demonstrated that it didn't work, then ask why you would use it.

Comment: Change the `&&` to `;` -- it could be one line, but not one command.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, won't work. Not in `bash`, not in `ksh`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller See my answer

Answer (score 5):

From the `bash` manual:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>          confusing.  Bash always reads at least one complete line of input
>          before executing any of the commands on that line.  Aliases are
>          expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.  **Therefore,
>          an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does
>          not take effect until the next line of input is read.  The commands
>          following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the new
>          alias.**

This is also true in a number of other shells.

Answer (score 3):

You can work around the shell limitation by doing this:

```
eval 'alias xxx=echo
xxx ok'
```