# How can I write an `eval` command containing a new line into one line?

Tags: bash, alias, newlines, eval

Since I need to set and use alias in the same line in bash, I would like to use [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging)'s [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389997/16704):

```
eval 'alias df5=df
df5 -h'
```

(I took `df` and `df5` for the sake of the example. I am aware that in this specific example one could replace the entire `eval` command by `df -h`.)

However I would prefer to write this command into one line.

How can I write an `eval` command containing a new line into one line?

---

I unsuccessfully tried the following one-line commands:

- `eval 'alias df5=df\ndf5 -h'`. Error `-bash: alias: -h: not found`
- `alias df5=df ; df5`. Error: `No command 'df5' found`
- `alias df5=df && df5` (suggested by [Cyrus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74329/cyrus)). Error: `No command 'df5' found`

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using `bash`:

```
eval $'alias df5=df\ndf5 -h'
```

The `$'...'` is a "C string", and `bash` would expand the `\n` within it to a literal newline before passing it to `eval`.

Care must be taken as other backslash sequences would possibly also be expanded. See the [second half of the `QUOTING` section in the `bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If one answer was the "most helpful" you should accept it, that is one way to thank helpful answers and make it more visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, but all should hinge on the idea of writing a newline with other characters. The first possible solution, a portable one (very old) is to get a newline inside a variable:

```
nl='
'
eval 'alias df5=df'"$nl"'df5 -h'
```

The assignment of an explicit newline to a var may look odd, if that is the case, we can use:

- Ansi-C quoting (ksh,bash,zsh):

  ```
  nl=$'\n'
  ```
- printf (most shells):

  ```
  eval "$(printf "nl='\n'")"
  ```

But then, those two ideas might be used directly to define the alias:

```
eval $'alias df5=df\ndf5 -h'
eval "$(printf "alias 'df5=df\ndf5 -h'")"
```

But, of course, you can forget the newline, and define the alias as:

```
alias df5=df && df -h
```

But I am not sure if that would fit your use case. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives! Does `eval "$(printf "alias 'df5=df\ndf5 -h'")"` work on your side? It doesn't print anything in my bash.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It would not print anything as it just defines an alias. Checking with `alias df5` will confirm that the alias has been defined.